# torus volume calculation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I want to calculate the volume of a torus. I have tried the rough formula

> $\pi \cdot (1/2(r_{max}-r_{min}))^2 \cdot a$

but it gives me a larger value than what I predicted! What is the exact formula of the torus volume calculation?
Thank you!

Comment: Which torus????

Comment: Read on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry). I guess that formula is what you are after.

Comment: I have read it. I am not looking for the rough formula I mentioned. an exact mathematical formula is what I want. thank you!

Comment: @John What do you mean by which torus? I have created a torus by a fortran program. rmax and rmin are the parameters I have.

Comment: What do you denote `rmax` and `rmin`?

Comment: @Bernard rmax = 70 and rmin = 4 A. It is a sample ofcourse. I need a formula to calculate some other tori volume.

Comment: There is such a formula in the link  mentioned in a previous comment:$$V=2\pi^2\mathrm{rmax} \cdot\mathrm{rmin}^2.$$